# How to change social icon images in wordpress jetpack sharing

Tags: wordpress, sharing, jetpack

I want to change the social icon images in Jetpack sharing Wordpress, is there any way to change the social icon images with my own customized images.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change images by replace images jetpack-sharing\sharedaddy\images in images folder with your customized images.

Comment: I already tried it before, but the new image icon got stretched, probably due to the CSS of jetpack, can please some one help me , I need a detail asnwer

Comment: you can change jetpack css according to your appropriate css. if you have tried this also..then i can only ask you for your images to replace/update. share your code here...